# publishing file stream with ros

Tags: ros, stream, rosmsg

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I would like to create a service which publish as a topic a byte stream with the content of a file. It is possible to define inside a Ros service a data type variables ifstream? or could it be possible to use a primitive type for this purpose?
Best Regards

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10408/publishing-file-stream-with-ros/) by [cmsoda](https://answers.ros.org/users/430/cmsoda/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2011-06-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can only use some basic [data types](http://www.ros.org/wiki/msg). For your application you would use a primitive type (probably an uint8[]).

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2011-06-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0